# Polymer - right justify paper-tabs

Tags: polymer

For `paper-tabs`, I am trying to justify the container to the right in the `paper-toolbar`...so the `title` is on the left and the `paper-tabs` are on the right. I used `justify-content: flex-end;` but no success.

http://jsbin.com/girenekava/1/edit?html,output

Please make sure not to enable flex for the `paper-tabs` children as I have disabled on purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a class 'title' in your div who have the title, like this:

```
 <div class="title">
      Title
 </div>
```